# Why Ip in django honybot is None

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, honeypot

I download honeypot using bib and added it in my url django project file, and I use it in my website that is production, I use nginx. and why Honeypot return `<a href="?ip_address=None">None</a>`